# Adding dynamic items to listview

Tags: android

Hi I want to add an item to a listview.

This is my New message activity in which I wan to pass an item to my Main Activity.  I'm not quite sure how to pass this data through an intent any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class NewMessage extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText new_message;
    Button post_new_message_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_message);

        new_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_content);
        post_new_message_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.message_send);


        post_new_message_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                TextView username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.conversation_username2);

                itemAdapter.add(new MessageItem(1656,"Bill Smith", "image", DateTime.now(), new_message.getText().toString()));

                itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                if (v.getId() == R.id.message_send);
                new_message.setText("");

            }
        });

    }

}
```

This is my main activity I want to pass in the data

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
TextView threadId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button newMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_message_button);


    newMessage.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent newMessage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewMessage.class);
            startActivity(newMessage);
        }

    });

    final ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.messagingListView);
    final ActivityAdapter itemAdapter = new ActivityAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this.MessageFeedData());

    listView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);


        }
    });
}
// Get dummy data for Activity Feed

    public ArrayList<MessageItem> MessageFeedData() {
        ArrayList<MessageItem> items = new ArrayList<MessageItem>();

        items.add(new MessageItem(1, "Bob Doe", "image", DateTime.now(), "Hello how are you?"));
        items.add(new MessageItem(200, "John Smith", "image", DateTime.now(), "Hello what are you doing"));


        return items;
    }


    class ActivityFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

        ArrayList<MessageItem> recentTracks;


    }


    public class ActivityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MessageItem> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<MessageItem> items;
        //private int currentPage = 0;

        public ActivityAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessageItem> recentTrackArrayList) {
            super(context, 0, recentTrackArrayList);
            this.context = context;
            this.items = recentTrackArrayList;
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView;


            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate
                        (R.layout.message_list_item, parent, false);

                //final MessageItem item = items.get(position);

                rowView = convertView;

                TextView comment2 = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.messaging_username);
                comment2.setText(items.get(position).Username);

                ImageView comment3 = (ImageView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.messaging_photo);
                if (items.get(position).Image == null) {
                    comment3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }

                TextView comment4 = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.messaging_date);
                comment4.setText(items.get(position).DateTimeStamp.toString());

                TextView comment5 = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.messaging_string);
                comment5.setText(items.get(position).MessageString);


            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you planning on storing your messages?  You should at least store them to a SQLite database locally.  You could also store them in a database on a server and use a php script to send you the messages in json format.

Comment: Currently I'm testing with dummy data before plugging this into the api so they wouldn't be stored

Comment: What api will you be using?  I would think you should send new messages to be saved using your api in NewMessage, then in MainActivity retrieve any new messages using the api, and update the adapter there.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to pass data back and forth between the two activities, maybe you should use:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
```

and

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

So that when the NewMessageActivity finishes, it can send the data back to  the main activity.